# Deleting rows that have no associated row in another table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables with a few columns:

```
parent (id, name, a) 
child (id, parent_id, name)
```

I cannot manage to find the proper SQL query to delete all parents that have no children and a<10. This is for SQLite shipped with Android 2.1. Anybody could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delete from parent
where a < 10
      and not exists (select * from child where parent.id = child.parent_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
delete from parent
where a < 10
and id not in (select parent_id from child, parent b where child.parent_id = b.id)
```